# How to access the array of array in mongoDb

Tags: mongodb

I'm facing with mongodb for querying the array of array fields
I am able to access the 'feild1.feild2' but its returns the value 
field1:{field2:[Array]}

```
field1:Object
  field2:[Array]
     0:Array
        0:Object
```

My Real Dataset are:

```
customerData:Object
 sendtocustomerlist:[Array]
    0:Array
      0:Object
         Name:xxx
         phone:xxxxxxx
```

I want to access the field2 and the nested arrays to get the Object values. Help with that.

Comment: Please share dataset and your desired result.

Comment: Can you share the code you have tried.

Comment: `db.customer.aggregate([
   {
     $project:
      {
         first: { $arrayElemAt: [ "$customerdata.tosendcustomerslist", 0 ] },
      }
   }` the following code gives me the result like _first:[Object]_

Answer (score 0):

you can use `arrayElemAt`:
here is the link:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/#exp._S_arrayElemAt

Comment: Hi @Ali Hallaji  the link u send is helped me but still am facing some small issue..

Comment: what is your issues?